# Webpack, postcss and nanocss: how to set global variable for CSS

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, postcss

I have a node project using Webpack, postcss and its plugin nanocss.

For JavaScript code, I've set a global variable `VERSION` retrieved from package.json: doing this is straightforward setting webpack.config.js as:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
    })
  ]
};
```

In this way I can access the `VERSION` variable in anyone of my JavaScript module.

Now, I would like to do the same with css.
Using nanocss, I can put a comment in my main.css with `/*! version: 0.0.1`, but I would like to have the same variable taken from package.json like for JavaScript, in order to do `/*! version: VERSION*/`

How to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved not using webpack.config.js but postcss.config.js as described in this [github discussion](https://github.com/gridonic/postcss-replace/issues/3)!